# Github backup repository (incl. issues) and transfer to another user

Tags: git, github

i am trying to backup a rather large repository including all issues and comments and transfer/copy it to another user. So basically after that, there should be two users with exactly the same repository including all issues etc, both owning the repository.
Is that possible?

I looked deeper into the API to backup the repository and all issues, but I couldn't find how to transfer that backup to another user.

Forking also does not seem to work, as the issues cannot be transferred with the repository.

Many thanks

Comment: *Git* doesn't have issues and PRs and so on; those are GitHub add-ons. I don't believe GitHub allow en-masse copying of their non-Git database entries that hold these.

Comment: Yes exactly, the Github issues and comments. So far I was only able to find Backhub, a non-free service that does what I am looking for. But thanks anyways!